# infer typescript args for dynamically created functions

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure this is possible in TS, but the SO community keeps on surprising me so giving this a shot:

I have a routes object that I'm dynamically converting to functions for both the static and dynamic use, so given the route `/posts/:id`, I can do:

```
// static declaration, output is /posts/:id
<Route path={ROUTES.singlePost()} />

// dynamic use, id = 1, output is /posts/1
naivigate(ROUTES.singlePost(someId)
```

I'm constructing the object like so:

```
const rawRoutes = [{ key: "singlePost", path: "/posts:id:" }]

export const ROUTES = rawRoutes.reduce(
  (acc, item) => ({
    ...acc,
    [item.key]: buildRouteFn(item.path),
  }),
  {} as Record<IRouteKey, (...args: string[]) => string>,
)

function buildRouteFn(path: string) {
  return (...args: string[]) =>
    args.reduce((_path, arg) => _path.replace(/:\w+/, arg), path)
}

type IRouteKey = typeof rawRoutes[number]["key"]
```

This gives me the following autocomplete
[image]

and as you can see I can't see the actual args in there (`postId?: string`)

Is there a way for TS to infer this dynamically?

I can fallback to:

```
export const ROUTES = {
  singlePostStatic: () => "/posts/:id",
  singlePostDynamic: (id: string) => `/posts/:${id}`,
}
```

But it's much more readable/maintainable to have a plain object

Comment: Welp, this is a lot more complicated than I thought: https://tsplay.dev/wOAo7m

Comment: Are there typos in this?  Do you really have two colons in `"/posts:id:"`?  Are you looking for `(arg1?: string, arg2?: string, arg3?: string) => string` if the path has 3 colons in it?  Or are you looking for something more specific than that?

Comment: I expect [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJXoZN) to be what you're looking for; am I right?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: Both your approaches work, tho when hovering the function I see `arg_0` instead of `id`. Is there a way to get that as well?